# How to fix the Any method seemingly returning true in If statement no matter what

Tags: c#

I'm trying to determine if an error message on a generated text file contains the word "multiple", "Database", or both. For each text file I have I'm evaluating which word(s) it contains and for now am just using a messaging box to see how it evaluates. From what I can tell the first if statement is the only one that returns true, even though both text .txt files I have in the folder each only have one of the key words. Code below.

I've searched to see if I have the Exclamation point in the wrong position in the else if statements, but from what I've found it looks right.

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\temp\test", "*.txt");

        var multi = "multiple";
        var data = "Database";

        for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
        {
            var sheet = File.ReadAllText(files[i]);

            if (multi.Any(sheet.Contains) && data.Any(sheet.Contains))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Both");
            }
            else if (multi.Any(sheet.Contains) && !data.Any(sheet.Contains))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Just Multiple");

            }else if(!multi.Any(sheet.Contains) && data.Any(sheet.Contains))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Just Database");
            }
```

So the first file only has the word "multiple" in it. The first if statement should return false since both conditions aren't met since the first any method returned true while the second shouldn't. But from what I can tell both are returning true.

Comment: `multiple` and `database` both contain the letter `e`.

Answer (score 5):

Let's break down your problem:

- `multi` is a `string`.
- LINQ extension methods (of which `.Any()` is one) operate on `IEnumerable<>`.
- the enumerable for string is `IEnumerable<char>`, so `.Any()` will operate on this.
- The string `Contains()` method will accept a `string` or a `char`.

So what's happening? You are checking if *any* of the characters in `multi` (i.e. `m`, `u`, `l`, `t`, `i`, `p`, `l`, `e`) are found in the string `sheet`.

What you actually want to write is simply `if (sheet.contains(multiple))`, etc.

Fixing your current code, it should look like this:

```
if (sheet.Contains(multi) && sheet.Contains(data))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Both");
}
else if (sheet.Contains(multi) && !sheet.Contains(data))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Just Multiple");

}
else if(!sheet.Contains(multi) && sheet.Contains(data))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Just Database");
}
```

Though I'd probably avoid doing `sheet.Contains` over and over (especially on bigger files), and instead do those calculations first:

```
bool containsMulti = sheet.Contains(multi);
bool containsData = sheet.Contains(data);

if (containsMulti && containsData)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Both");
}
else if (containsMulti && !containsData)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Just Multiple");
}
else if (!containsMulti && containsData)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Just Database");
}
```

And as [@Kristianne Nerona](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1094751/kristianne-nerona) notes, you could simply change the last `else if` to an `else`, since if the prior two conditions were both false, only one possibility remains.

Comment: May I suggest eliminating !containsMulti and !containsData on the second code block for brevity?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, this all makes a lot more sense now that you explained the IEnumerable interface.

Comment: Glad to hear it :-)